# How to install Eclipse J2EE IDE from a tarball?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse 3.6.1 as a tar.gz file from eclipse site. Then I extract using 
cmd: `tar -zxvf eclipse-jee-helios-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz`

after execute this cmd I got eclipse folder in this there is eclipse file. When I double click on this eclipse file I'm getting following error:

> Could not display "/media/D-DEVELOPME/eclipse/eclipse".

There is no application installed for executable files

is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

As Marcos Roriz and Thomas Ward said in the comments

> That happens because eclipse writes a lot of temp and plugin files and /usr/local is recommended to not allow apps to write (that is only read and execute there)
>
> You may have better luck just saving Eclipse down onto your user directory - it does still operate from the user directory, even though you may want to place it in /usr/ or elsewhere. This is what I do to use it :/

Answer (score 0):

install your eclipse in your home directory or /usr/local/ directory :D

Comment: yes, it's working fine if I extract under file System directory. but not working if I extract any other directory.

Comment: @Silambarasan that happens because eclipse writes a lot of temp and plugin files and /usr/local is recommended to not allow apps to write (that is only read and execute there)

Comment: @Silambarasan: You may have better luck just saving Eclipse down onto your user directory - it does still operate from the user directory, even though you may want to place it in /usr/ or elsewhere.  This is what I do to use it :/